# How to get result from select option?

Tags: jquery, html, forms, select

I want to make a select option , where for each option display a different html text on div.

```
<form>
    <label>Select Country:</label>
    <select class="country">
        <option value="1">United States</option>
        <option value="2">India</option>
        <option value="3">United Kingdom</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

and jquery .

```
$("select.country").change(function(){
    var selectedCountry = $(".country option:selected").val();
   // alert("You have selected the country - " + selectedCountry);
    $('#mydiv').prepend('<h2> option one </h2>');
});
```

How can i achieve this . any idea.

Thanks

Comment: Your code should work. However, Where is your `mydiv`? and simply use `var selectedCountry = $(this).val();$('#mydiv').prepend('<h2>' +selectedCountry  +'</h2>');`

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: You don't have mydiv in your html so it won't do anything

Comment: `.val()` will just return one of the numbers `1`, `2`, `3`. If you want the name of the country, use `.text()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, something like this should work for you: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wrxsti85/8wz18752/)

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <label>Select Country:</label>
    <select class="country">
        <option disabled>Please select a country</option>
        <option value="us">United States</option>
        <option value="india">India</option>
        <option value="uk">United Kingdom</option>
    </select>
</form>
<div id="uk" class="countryOption"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/ae/Flag_of_the_United_Kingdom.svg" /><br />Text about the UK</div>
<div id="us" class="countryOption"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1a/US_flag_48_stars.svg/220px-US_flag_48_stars.svg.png" /><br />Text about the US </div>
<div id="india" class="countryOption"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikip1/Flag_of_India.svg/225px-Flag_of_India.svg.png" /><br />Text about India</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("select.country").change(function(){
    var selectedCountry = $(this).val();
    $('.countryOption').hide()
    $('#' + selectedCountry).show();
});
```

Let me know if I am off base here. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply.. Its close..
i have different text with images for each country . So, when i change to uk , i  want to display uk related text or div . which might be display none , by default. 

i want similar this result : http://nimb.ws/luTJca

thanks

Comment: How about this? Updated the code and the demo. Maybe this is closer?

Comment: No problem. Any time :)

Comment: Hi,, wrxsti.. 

How can i make a another select option . like : select continent , then , will display , Select country ,, rest are same .. 
can you please , help me on this..

Thanks Advance ..

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(".country").change(function(){
       var selectedCountry = $(".country").val();
        var text = $('.country option:selected').text();
        var text1='You have selected:';
   if( selectedCountry > 0 ){
      
  $('#mydiv').html(text1+text );
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <select class="country">
    <option>Please Select </option>
    <option value="1">India </option>
    <option value="2">UK </option>
    <option value="3">Canada </option>
    <option value="4">Iran </option>
  </select>
  <div id="mydiv"> </div>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
 
function getval(){

   var selectedCountry = $('select[name=selector] option:selected').text();
    alert("You have selected the country - " + selectedCountry);
    $('#mydiv').prepend('<h2> option one </h2>');

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <label>Select Country:</label>
    <select class="country" onChange="getval();" name='selector'>
        <option value="1">United States</option>
        <option value="2">India</option>
        <option value="3">United Kingdom</option>
    </select>
</form>
```